# Footer overlapping content in printed page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write a long HTML page which, when printed, contains a footer that says "For Official Use Only (FOUO)".  I have it positioned absolutely at the bottom of the page, but the content of the page also goes down that far, or the footer overlaps.  I have tried setting up my @media print CSS such that the main content of a page is 50 pixels less than the full height of the page, but this doesn't do anything.  Here is my CSS:

```
@media print {
#content {
    max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
#printFooter {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto
}
```

}

This goes with an HTML file with the following form:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">Lots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first page</div>
    <div id="printFooter">For Official Use Only (FOUO)</div>
</body>
```

Can someone please help me figure out how to set up my CSS so that the content doesn't get overlapped at the bottom of the page?

Chris

Comment: are you trying to get the footer on the bottom of every printed page, or just 1 footer at the very bottom of the last page?

Comment: By me it works perfectly https://plnkr.co/edit/wkINSBwXfCWGqi4uwTVd?p=preview

Comment: I am trying to get the footer on the bottom of every printed page, but can't get it to work.  If I print preview, it doesn't show it on all pages.

Comment: @Chris Did you find any solution for this problem? I have the same issue. Please tell me how you fixed that

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find a solution.  The people who use this tool have had to use a pdf editor to add the footer to the resulting Word file.

Comment: I have also same issue

Answer (score -1):

I found only this solution, but we lose some text(

```
<body>
    <div id="content">Lots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first page<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Lots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first page<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Lots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first page<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Lots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first page<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Lots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first page<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Lots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first pageLots of text in this div to make it extend beyond first page</div>
    <div id="printFooter">For Official Use Only (FOUO)</div>
</body>

@media print {
    #printFooter {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto
}
```

Comment: Else this can control through some divs that will showed in print version and does extra padding

Comment: I just tried the code above with one addition.  I added a border and padding to the content section within the media print:
[code]@media print {
    #content {
     padding-bottom: 50px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid;
    }
    #printFooter {
     position: fixed;
     text-align: center;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     background: #fff;
     margin: 0 auto 0 auto
    }
   }[/code]
I'm getting the footer at the bottom of each page, but on the first page, it overlaps the middle of the last line of text.  And the border only appears on the 2nd page.